# Car window locking pins frozen, cannot pull the pin up

Tags: locks, door

Did it ever happen to anyone in cold weather? I literally could not pull up the pins with my fingers to open the door until inside the car heats up. What can I do if it happens again?

Answer (score 1):

Two things may help before it happens again:

1) lubricate the pins with silicone - a light coating,

But better:
2) is to dehumidify the inside of the car - sounds like it has too much moisture in it if those pins can ice up.